# Installing Laravel and more importantly Elixir on Shared Hosting [OOM]

Tags: node.js, linux, laravel, npm, laravel-elixir

So,

For two days now I'm struggling to install Laravel 5.3 on a shared hosting. First it was the PHP version, php-cli version, then it was tons of other stuff that one by one I tackled. After that I had to spent like a whole day trying to install node and npm (to work with elixir) and to make the `node` and `npm` commands work in the line. I did that.

So now the problem is `npm install` runs for a while and then goes out with

`FATAL ERROR: Zone Allocation failed - process out of memory`

Whatever I did it was to no avail. I spent hours in Google and Stack Overflow none of the solutions work. Since upping the memory is not an option (and that server actually has more than enough RAM to offer) there **has to be** a way to run `npm install` without eating all the RAM...

`node -v
 v6.9.1
 npm -v
 3.10.8
 uname -a
 Linux fly.icnhost.net 3.10.94-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Dec 10 12:39:34   EST 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I don't know what information would be helpful for you, guys, so I'll be answering any questions you have right away.

Thank you very much in advance, trying to tackle this for two damn days now! :)

Comment: What are the specs of this server? It sounds like you're really running out of RAM and there's no SWAP available.

Comment: That's the other thing. There is no `free` or `top/htop` commands available (apparently due to the shared hosting. Any idea how I can check the exact RAM I have available? And also - how can I make SWAP available?

Comment: Do you have sudo/su access?

Comment: I do not think so... I am starting to think that it is possible to do `npm install` locally and then upload the dependencies via ftp ...